# What Hulk titles are great for a newbie?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, the-incredible-hulk

I'm a comic newbie in general and I just picked up Hulk essential Volume 1 (I.H 1-6, Tales to Astonish 60-91 inside). I like it so far.

But the continuity of a lot of these older comics threatens to alienate new readers like me from reading this awesome type of medium... So here's the real question:

Should I continue reading the Hulk essential volumes for a good background on the Hulk? Or can I jump in the newer volumes, or will I get a bit confused because I'll be missing some background (but  potentially still enjoy it)?

So: Where is it best for me to start?

Note:
I kind of want to learn more about Betty as well cause I looked her up and apparently she died....
And
Hulk: Gray seems like a good story and more in depth than the original Hulk origin....)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Peter David's run starting with issue 331, it was, in my opinion , the best storyline in a long time.
Issues 331 to 346 were mostly pencilled by Todd McFarlane before he became famous
[image: Mc Farlane's Hulk]

Later on an even better artist came on board, namely Dale Keown from issue 367 till 398 with some interruptions. it's during this run that David explained the multiple colors and personalities of the Hulk, i won't spoil it but it's really brilliant.

[image: Dale Keown]

After this run, i think the hulk comic lost its interest until World War Hulk, an amazing epic, well written and beautifully penciled

[image: World War Hulk]

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Awesome answer! Could you clarify, with an [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/35344/edit), why Peter David's run was the best? Does it cover the hulk's origin, for instance?

Comment: Thanks, not sure I can add more to my previous answer, as i mentioned it's my opinion, so probably questionable :-). There are a few things i find memorable during David's run, but the most interesting thing is that he was able to explain the different incarnations of the character (green hulk, gray hulk, angry hulk, smart hulk, stupid hulk etc) with an inventive an plausible explanation, i don't want to spoil it so i'll let you read it :-)